# How does Pandas Merge as of (pd.merge_asof) 'left_by' and right_by' work?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, left-join, right-join

I have a dataframe with two columns  in which one is `'date_time'` value and other `(position)` is a float. I have to merge two dataframes such that difference between the date_time values of the two frames is less than `30 min` and position difference is less than `100 (metres)`. How do I do this?. I used merge_asof and used left_by and right_by.But its giving the error

```
MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False
```

`I have a common column 'ID' though it doesnt have same values in both frames`. How can I accomplish this.From Documentation my understanding is that left_by and right_by is used when more than two columns is used.I have also tolerance to get the difference between them ~ 30 min ,but I also need the position `difference to be ~ 100m`
Can I give tolerance as a list like `('tolerance' = pd.Timedelta('30min'),100)` I dont know. Or if not possible is there some other way?

Comment: take a little bit time reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101/53645883

Comment: There is no 'how' option in pd.merge_asof!

Comment: I am using pd.merge_asof

Comment: by is for exactly merge , on is for the tolerance merge in merge_asof

Comment: Ok So can I give multiple columns for merge and only merge them if both column tolerance is as mentioned above

Comment: Multiple will not work